# Tableau Server REST API to check if view exists

Tags: rest, tableau-api

### Is there any way to check if a view exists in the site based on its share URL ?

(*Tableau Server Version 10.3, Tableau Server REST API version 2.6*)

**Input:** (*share URL of a view*)

`http://my-tableau-server/views/my-workbook-name/my-view-name?:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no`

**Output:**
Boolean flag indicating whether the view represented by this share URL exists in a site or not.

---

I found one option to [Query Views for Site](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_Views_for_Site) where [filtering on views](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_filtering_and_sorting.htm) is applicable **only** on the following fields and not on the contentUrl field:

- name
- createdAt
- hitsTotal
- ownerName
- tags
- updatedAt

I do not want to get all the views of a site and filter in my dot net code. Please suggest if there is any other option available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the Tableau API, there are only two endpoints that allow all views of Sites or a Workbook.  Both endpoints don't let you search for a specific view.

The only ways to accomplish what you are trying to do is to filter via the .Net code.